Hawaiian Earring vs. My Space: Fundamental groups
While thinking about the Hawaiian earring space $H$, I thought of a two point compactification of the union of a family of disjoint open intervals $$\large\large\amalg_{n=1}^\infty(0,1)$$ call this $J$. The fundamental group of $H$ is uncountable.

How do you calculate the fundamental group of $J$? Is it uncoubable like the fundamental group of $H$?

I drew $H$ and $J$ below:


@freakish gotcha

I think "my space", as you drew it, is not a two point compactification of a sum of a countably infinite family of open intervals: If you remove the two "end points", the interval in the "middle" is not open, hence the remainder is not the sum of the intervals.

I guess, a two point compactification of the sum of a countably infinite family of open intervals looks like Hawaiian earring with a closed interval attached to its "centre".

@Ulli attached where exactly?

In your drawing to the left: if the centre point in your drawing is $(0,0)$, then consider its union with $[-1, 0] \times { 0 }$.

It should also be noted that, in contrast to one point compactifications, two point compactifications need not be unique. For instance, in this case, the Hawaiian earing itself is a two point compactification (removing the centre and any other point leaves a sum of countably many open intervals).

Before we talk about $J$ space, lets briefly talk about the Hawaiian earring $H$. The Hawaiian earring is not the wedge sum of infinitely many circles. I remember I was super confused the first time I've heard about it. But yes, (infinite or not) wedge sum of locally contractible spaces is locally contractible. But $H$ is not locally contractible, every open connected neighbourhood of the base point contains a copy of $H$, in fact is homotopy equivalent to $H$. And so $H$ cannot be decomposed into simpler pieces, unlike the wedge sum.
There is also a big difference with regards to the fundamental group. Every path in an infinite wedge sum of circles can go around only finitely many circles. But that's not the case for $H$, paths can go around infinitely many circles. That's because $H$ has the additional property that those circles "converge" to the base point. So $H$ has essentially more paths than wedge sum. And that's the intuition behind the fact that $\pi_1(H)$ is big.
Now lets talk about your $J$. You did not define the "two point compactification" term. So there are multiple non-equivalent options here:

We take the disjoint union $\coprod_{n=1}^\infty [0,1]$ of closed intervals and then we glue all left ends together and we glue all right ends together. It matches your drawing, however it is not compact. This space is very similar to wedge sum of circles, and it shares many properties with it (in fact I think these are homotopy equivalent). In particular it can be decomposed into simpler pieces, so for example (infinite) van Kampen applies to it. Or we can use an infinite sequence of ascending open subsets, like here, to conclude that $\pi_1(J)$ is a countable direct limit of countable groups, and therefore it has to be countable.
To ensure compactness we can take something similar to $H$, a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ consisting of countably many arcs between $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$ points, converging towards $X$ axis, together with the straight line connecting those points. This space is a compactification of the open intervals, although not really two-point (we attached whole interval, the $X$ axis). However its topology is a lot more complicated then the previous one. Similarly to $H$ open neighbourhoods of the $X$ interval contain copies of itself. But unlike $H$ a path can go around only finitely many circles, due to the fact that this space is not locally connected (and image of a path is locally connected). I don't know how to formally calculate the fundamental group of this space, but my intuition tells me it is countable as well. Maybe someone else can fill the details.
In fact the Hawaiian earring itself is a two point compactification of those open intervals. We can see this by removing the base point and any other point. I suspect that's not what you want to talk about though.

Honestly, I'm not sure how to construct other path connected compactification of $\coprod_{n=1}^\infty (0,1)$ via exactly two points. It must be wild if it exists.

The space $J$, as you describe it, should not be compact: the set of all mid points is closed, discrete.

@Ulli fair enough, I've updated the answer.

About two point compactifications: they are not that weird, see my comments above.

@Ulli I can make the "arcs" in $J$ converge to the central midline. Is this wildly different from the circles converging to one point in $H$?

@JohnZimmerman together with the midline? This is my construction 2, which is not two-point, but it is a compactification. Without midline? This is not compact, and it is my construction 1 as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

@freakish ohh okay got it see it now! Thanks. By the way the generalization of this I had in mind was nested spheres that each share a common pair of antipodal points which lie $(0,0,0)$ and $(1,0,0).$ The difference in this case is the spheres converge to the same interval $(0,1)$.

@freakish see my above comments for further two point compactifications
(also you bullet point 3 appeared in one of my comments before).
And there are still many others, for instance the sum of a circle and a Hawaiian earing, or of two Hawaiian earings etc.

@Ulli the sum of a circle and a Hawaiian earring, or two Hawaiian earrings are homeomorphic to Hawaiian earring. Yes, glueing additional single dangling interval is an option, but not an interesting one IMO.

@freakish No, they are not connected.

@Ulli Oh, you mean disjoint union? That is not interesting as well in the context of fundamental groups. Lets agree that only path connected spaces are interesting.

@freakish yes, of course, "sum" = disjoint union. And yes, I was not looking for interesting examples in the context of fundamental groups. Just for reasonable two point compactifications.
